# ninject interceptor - helper methods

Tags: ninject, aop, interceptor

I have a simply interface:

```
public interface ITest
{
      void Method1();
      void Method2();
}
```

and implementation:

```
public class Test:ITest
{
      public void Method1()
      {

      }
      public void Method2()
      {
           //Method1();
      }
}
```

The custom interceptor:

```
public class CustomInterceptor:IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
          invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Now, when I execute there two methods:

```
ITest obj = getting through ninject
obj.Method1();
obj.Method2();
```

my interceptor is calling twice what is ok.
But when I uncomment the body of Method2(), then the interceptor for the Method1() is not called. I'm looking for what to do, because I want the interceptor to be fired.
When I call the Method1 from the second, I understand this is not called by the generated proxy and that's why it doesn't work. But is it possible to do it in same way?

Answer (score 1):

Ninject creates a proxy object around the actual instance of the Test class. Your methods aren't virtual, so any override for the proxy should be created with 'new' rather than 'override'. Thus, if you call Method1 from Method2, there is no virtual lookup to find the proxy and invoke it.